# Infinite groups in which every element is a commutator

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory

Finite groups in which every element is a commutator are considered in many works. How about infinite group case? Are there any recent results or constructions related to infinite groups in which every element is a commutator?

Comment: Take a product of infinitely many non-trivial finite groups in which every element is a commutator. What is the question here?

Comment: This becomes interesting when you assume finite generation of the group.

Comment: There are infinite groups in which all non-identity elements are conjugate. It is immediate that every element is a commutator in such a group.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson And even finitely presented ones. https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0411039v3.pdf

Comment: Every element of a compact semi-simple Lie group is a commutator.

Comment: In https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.08740.pdf Gal and Gismatulln consider groups in which every element is a product of a small number of commutators.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think you are missing something in your comment, and it is not obvious to me why Tarski monsters have this property (It is clear the commutator subgroup is the whole group but it isn't clear that every element is a commutator to me)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Do you really mean to say that "any infinite non-Abelian group will satisfy this"? An infinite non-Abelian which is not perfect (such as an infinite dihedral group) certainly has no chance to do so:

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: I am certainly missing words; sorry.

Comment: @PaulPlummer: Urgh; quite right.